# Inner product on Hilbert Spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

It's an open question. How could you define an inner product for a product of noncontable Hilbert spaces?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you take as the product of uncountably many spaces? Is the support finite ?

Comment: The _product_ of infinitely many nontrivial Hilbert spaces is not a normable space. One usually considers the Hilbert sum rather than the product in such cases.

Comment: I guess there is simply no direct product for infinite number of Hilbert spaces; but one needs to prove this. In Categorical Perspectives by Koslowsky and Melton it says "A category **A** *has (finite) products* if there exists a product for each (finite) set-indexed family of of objects in **A**." (Definition 1.12, p. 5). So it suggests that it really can happen that some family constitutes no product...

Comment: I opened a thread on this question, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810672/category-with-no-product/810678?noredirect=1#comment1675203_810678

Answer (score 1):

When you have a family of Hilbert spaces $\mathcal H_\alpha$, $\alpha\in A$, a natural thing to do is to

1. Introduce a measure $\mu$ on the set $A$.
2. Consider the space of functions $f$ from $A$ into the formal disjoint union $\bigsqcup_\alpha \mathcal H_\alpha$. Require $f(\alpha)\in\mathcal H_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$. Also require $\int_A \|f(\alpha)\|_{\mathcal H_\alpha}^2\,d\mu(\alpha)<\infty$.
3. Define the inner product as $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_A \langle f(\alpha), g(\alpha)\rangle  \,d\mu(\alpha)$.
4. Worry about measurability in the above integrals.
5. Decide that two cases are enough for practical purposes:

   5a.  $\mu$ is a counting measure on $A$
   5b. All $\mathcal H_\alpha$ are the same space
6. Stop worrying about  measurability and go on enjoying your life.