# Category with no product?

Tags: category-theory, products, direct-product

Is there a family of objects in some category which has no product? If so is there a simple reason for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three examples for your enjoyment:

1. Let $C$ be a discrete category, so that the only morphisms are the identity morphisms. If $a, b \in C$ are distinct objects, then the product $a \times b$ does not exist. Indeed, we must have $C(d, a \times b) = C(d, a) \times C(d, b)$ for all objects $d$; but since $a\neq b$, at least one of the two sets $C(d, a)$ and $C(d, b)$ is empty, hence $C(d, a \times b)$ is empty for all $d$. This is impossible, since when $d=a\times b$ there should be the identity morphism.
2. Let $\mathbf Q$ be considered as a total order. If $S\subset \mathbf Q$, the product $\prod_{s \in S} s$ in this category is nothing but $\sup S$, when this $\sup$ is a rational number. When $\sup S$ is irrational or infinite, the product does not exist. Obviously, all finite nonempty products exist.
3. In any category, the empty product is a terminal object. Thus, when $C$ has no terminal object, the empty product does not exist in $C$.

Comment: Well, if $a\to b$ is interpreted as $a\le b$ in $\Bbb Q$ in your example 2., then $\prod_{s\in S}s$ is rather the *infimum* of $S$.

Comment: @Berci You're right, that is probably the usual convention.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of examples here. For example, let $\mathsf{Ab}_f$ be the category of finitely-generated abelian groups and consider the family of $\mathsf{Ab}_f$-objects $\{A_i:i\in\Bbb N\}$ where $A_i=\Bbb Z$. Then $\prod A_i$ does not exist in $\mathsf{Ab}_f$.

Note, however, that the [Yoneda embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_embedding#The_Yoneda_embedding) $\mathscr{C}\to[\mathscr C^{\DeclareMathOperator{op}{op}\op},\mathsf{Set}]$ is a fully-faithful functor from any category $\mathscr C$ into the complete category $[\mathscr C^{\DeclareMathOperator{op}{op}\op},\mathsf{Set}]$.

Comment: Sure $\prod_iA_i$ is not in $\mathbf{Ab}_f$ but that doesn't say that there might be another construction just think of the analogue problem that the vector space direct sum of Banach spaces is not the actual Banach space direct sum of Banach spaces... But I guess your example shows already what may usually happens that the space will be to big as in the case of infinite products of Hilbert spaces

Comment: @Freeze: countable products can't exist in the category of finitely generated abelian groups essentially for dimension reasons. Namely, if $\prod \mathbb{Z}$ exists, then $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \prod \mathbb{Z}) \cong \prod \mathbb{Z}$ fails to be finitely generated, but if $A$ is any finitely generated abelian group then $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, A) \cong A$ is finitely generated. (Here I am using the fact that $\text{Ab}$ is canonically enriched over itself.)